# text search returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my query is returning me an empty array when I try to text search in mongodb I already created an index into my database.

For example:

I have 2 data type of String declared in my model status and mac_address both of them already included in the text index. When I search for a mac_address it gives me the correct data but when I tried to search for the status it returns an empty array.

```
--Model--

const PhoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  status: {
    type: String, 
    default: "DOWN"
  },
  mac_address: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
});

--Index--
db.phones.createIndex({
  status: "text",
  mac_address: "text"
});

--Route--
router.get('/search/:searchForData',
  async function (req, res) {
    try {
      const searchPhone = await Phone.find({
        $text: {
          $search: req.params.searchForData
        }
      }, {
        score: {
          $meta: "textScore"
        }
      }).sort({
        score: {
          $meta: "textScore"
        }
      })
      res.status(200).json(searchPhone);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: err.message
      });
    }
  });

db.phones.getIndexes()


[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "pingphony.phones"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "ip" : 1
                },
                "name" : "ip_1",
                "ns" : "pingphony.phones",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "mac" : 1
                },
                "name" : "mac_1",
                "ns" : "pingphony.phones",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "$**_text",
                "ns" : "pingphony.phones",
                "weights" : {
                        "$**" : 1
                },
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 3
        }
]
```

I expect the output of /phone/search/DOWN to be the data consisting of DOWN status but the actual output I get is []

Comment: try to remove score and sort from query. and show console.log  req.params.searchForData

Comment: Okay I will try that and update you.

Comment: @HilarionGalushka this the output of req.params.searchForData (DOWN)
typeof string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try making your query directly from mongo console:

   db.phones.find({ $text: { $search: "DOWN" }})
2. Try using aggregation pipeline:

   const searchPhone = await Phone.aggregate(
      [
        { $match: { $text: { $search: "DOWN" } } },
        { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
      ]
   );
3. If you tried everything and it just didn't go well try using regexp:

   const searchQuery = req.params.searchForData.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[]\]/g, '\$&'); // escape regexp symbols
     const searchPhone = await Phone.find({ status: new RegExp(`${searchQuery}`, 'i') });

Comment: Thank you for this I will test this.

Comment: Galusha this is working const searchQuery = req.params.searchForData.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[]\]/g, '\$&'); // escape regexp symbols const searchPhone = await Phone.find({ status: new RegExp(${searchQuery}, 'i') }); but how can I make the model status dynamic for example I want the mac_address to be search instead of status declaring variable to hold the variable is not working.

Comment: `const searchWord = req.params.searchForData.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[]\]/g, '\$&');
const searchRegExp = new RegExp(searchWord, 'i');
const searchQuery = {};
// here check if you want to search by mac_address or by status
// and assign searchQuery.status = searchRegExp.
// or searchQuery.mac_address = searchRegExp;
const searchPhone = await Phone.find(searchQuery);`

Comment: and please accept the answer if it was helpful. thanks!